# Removing Specific Characters from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

For example if i had a string like

```
NSString *myString = @"A B C D E F G";
```

and I want to remove the spaces, and get a string out like `"ABCDEFG"`.

I could use

```
NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

However, for my application I am loading in phone numbers from the address book
and the numbers often have a different formatting layout.

I'm wondering if I have a phone number stored in a string like
`+1-(937)673-3451` how would I go about removing only the first "1" the "+" the "-" and the "("  ")".

Overall, I would like to know if it is possible to remove the first "1" without removing the last one in the string?

Comment: You'll likely want to use `NSRegularExpression` to perform regex type replacements. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html

Comment: could you possibly provide and example of using NSRegularExpression?

Comment: Be very careful to evaluate the format as best as possible before removing any strings. Phone numbers are often poorly entered. It looks like you want to remove country codes. This is hard. Apple's private frameworks know what to do if there is a country code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Here's one:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"+1-(937)673-3451";
NSCharacterSet *removalCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+()-"];
NSArray *components = [phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:removalCharacterSet];
NSString *simplifiedPhoneNumber = [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSRange firstCharacterRange = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
if ([[simplifiedPhoneNumber substringWithRange:firstCharacterRange] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
     simplifiedPhoneNumber = [simplifiedPhoneNumber stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:firstCharacterRange withString:@""];
}
NSLog(@"Full phone number: %@", phoneNumber);
NSLog(@"Simplified phone number: %@", simplifiedPhoneNumber);
```

But really you want to use a library that knows what a phone number is supposed to look like, like [libPhoneNumber](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS).